# Glitch effect won't work

Tags: video-editor, after-effects, special-effects

I'm learning After Effects from scratch so sorry if this is obvious but whenever I try to make one part of an image 'glitch' I create a section of the image and place it in the middle but when I press play my desired glitch (JPG noise) does appear but black pixels appear outside the selected area of the image, anyone got any idea how I can stop this??

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Could you maybe add a link to a video (uploaded by you, or an existing one) showing the desired effect and you're problem? This would greatly help answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the "Bad TV" plugin to achieve this effect.  It has a setting to glitch images, and make them look as though the encoding has broken:

http://aescripts.com/bad-tv/

An example: